# PHP how to save png-file with a black background without the formation of extra colors?

Tags: php, png, gd

There is a picture with colored squares in base64, decoded: `$pngString = base64_decode($pngBase64);` 
After saving, near the squares appear pixels with other colors, they are not needed.
Tried 2 variants:
1. In this option, if you set a white background - everything is OK, with black too, but appear intermediate colors on borders (for example, if the rectangle is red, then there are claret pixels).

```
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($pngString);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $black);
    imagepng($img, $outputFilePath);
    imagedestroy($img);
```

2. Overlay on a new image:

   ```
   $img = imagecreatefromstring($pngString);
   $w = imagesx($img);
   $h = imagesy($img);
   $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imageantialias($img2, false);
   imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, $w, $h, imagecolorallocate($img2, 0, 0, 0));
   imagecopyresampled($img2, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h);
   imagepng($img2, $outputFilePath)
   ```

Comment: If you decode the base64 data straight to a PNG file, does it appear correct?

Comment: It sounds like those pixels have alpha channel transparency.  Please provide the image (base64 string?) in your question.  It's difficult to help you without being able to duplicate your problem.